# Law of sines: How to choose unknown angle

Tags: trigonometry

Say we know an angle $\alpha$ and two sides $a$ and $b$.
Let $b$ be the opposite side of the unknown angle $\beta$.

By the law of sines we have that

$\sin(\beta)=\frac{b \sin{\alpha}}{a}$.

When we want to know the value of $\beta$, is there a criterion to choose between $\arcsin{(\sin{\beta})}$ and $\pi-\arcsin{(\sin{\beta})}$?

Comment: It is not possible to know the angle $\beta$, since given $a$, $b$ and $\alpha$ there exists triangles with both angles.

Answer (score 1):

If $a\ge b$ holds, then $\beta < 90^{\circ}$ and is uniquely determined.
If $a<b$ holds, the following cases occur:

1. $\beta \ $ has two values for $\ b\sin \alpha < a \ (\beta_2= 180^{\circ}-\beta_1)$;
2. $\beta \ $ has exactly one value $(90^{\circ}) \ $ for $ \ b\sin \alpha = a$;
3. For $\ b\sin \alpha > a \ $ there is no such triangle.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in anothef answer, in some cases there is no solution or maybe a nonunique solution. In Euclidean geometry we fail to have an ASS congruence rule because of the possible nonuniqueness. (I recall a math teacher saying the donkey does not do what you want.)

In some cases you can use the Law of Cosines to decide the situation. Say you are given two sides and the included angle. You can use the Law of Cosines to get the third side. If you now try to use the Law of Sines to fill in the remaining angles you have two candidate roots for each angle, but knowing all three sides you can use the Law of Cosines again instead to get unique solutions for those angles. Try it, for instance, with a triangle having two known sides measuring five and eight units and the angle between them measuring $\pi/3$ radians.